# going through an array with forEach() , how does the code understand that a parameter is index and another is the element value?

Tags: javascript

Greeting guys , please take a look at this code

```
var array = [12, 929, 11, 3, 199, 1000, 7, 1, 24, 37, 4,
    19, 300, 3775, 299, 36, 209, 148, 169, 299,
    6, 109, 20, 58, 139, 59, 3, 1, 139];

function addHundredIfDivisionBY3Possible (element , i){
    if (element % 3 === 0) {
        array[i]= (element +=100) ;
    }
}


array.forEach(addHundredIfDivisionBY3Possible);
console.log (array);


output:
[ 112, 929, 11, 103, 199, 1000, 7, 1, 124, 37, 4, 19, 400, 3775, 299, 136, 209, 148, 169, 299, 106, 109, 20, 58, 139, 59, 103, 1, 139 ]
```

the question is how did the code understand that the "element" parameter is the value and i is for index , supposedly i meant it the other way around and i wrote the function like this

```
// wanting the  parameter 'element' to be the index and the parameter i to be the value of the element
function addHundredIfDivisionBY3Possible (element , i){
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
        array[element]= (i +=100) ;
    }

}
```

why is the first one working and the second one is not , it may have to do to with me trying to index the element un-properly " array[element] " but the question remains .. how does the program understand which parameter mean what ?

tried looking it up on google

Comment: Because that's how `forEach()` works. It calls the function repeatedly with each element and index as the arguments. The element is the first argument, the index is the second argument.

Comment: Did you try reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) of `forEach()`? It describes the arguments that are passed to the callback and the order they're passed.

Comment: @Barmar 
i think that i understood it as an example , didn't realise that it was the actual syntax 
( i thought forEach method has no arguments by default)

this answers my question , how can i mark it as the answer or is this a trivial question that should be deleted

Comment: @Barmar 
i'm fairly new to programming and i asked to understand how is it working in the background , i agree ..it doesn't make sense to not have a standard arguments order  

,thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// this is how forEach works (kind of)
function forEach(array, callback) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    // element is passed first
    // index is passed second
    callback(array[i], i)
  }
}

forEach(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], (e, i) => console.log('element', e, 'index', i))
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation , I wonder  which part is being left out? ( you wrote "kind of")   and your code explained it really well